# Count how many files and lines a given user deleted in git

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to understand how many lines I have deleted and how many file I have deleted
so far I got this:

```
git log --shortstat --since "Jan 1, 2022" --until "today" --author='Gilad Darmon <gilad.darmon@company.com>' | grep "files changed" | awk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6} END {print "files changed", files, "lines inserted:", inserted, "lines deleted:", deleted}'
```

the problem is every time you move files for example you get:

```
 9 files changed, 7406 insertions(+), 7402 deletions(-)
```

Is there a way just to count the deleted file?

any only lines which had deletion operation?

Comment: Just to be clear : "moved files" do not count as "deleted files", right ?

Comment: Trying to reproduce your question with a simple `git mv` for one file, the shortstat I get is `1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)`. In this experiment, Git is not counting plain moves, only actual edits. If I erase one line in the same commit as the move, I get `1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)`. Were those files edited in the same commit where they were moved?

Comment: In case it makes a difference, I am using Git 2.38.1 on Windows to try to reproduce your question.

Comment: Yes moved are no deleted

Comment: Don't use git move. Just move the files to a different folder and create a git commit